# selecting elements in WebDriver using xpath

Tags: xpath, webdriver

How do I select only the parent span webelement and not the child?

List  summaryLinks = summary.findElements(By.xpath(""));

My HTML code :

```
<li>
<div class="mod-indent mod-indent-2">
<a href="http://mysite.com">
<img class="activityicon" alt="URL" src="http://mysite.com">
<span class="instancename">LinkText <span class="accesshide "> URL</span></span>
</a>
</div>
</li>
```

I tried the following xpaths but didn't work
.//div[@class='mod-indent mod-indent-2']/a/span[@class='instancename']

.//div[@class='mod-indent mod-indent-2']/a/span[1]

.//div[@class='mod-indent mod-indent-2']/a/span/.

.//div[@class='mod-indent mod-indent-2']/a/span [position() =1]

.//div[@class='mod-indent mod-indent-2']/a/span/span [position() =1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple ways, but just a few:

```
By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'mod-indent-2')]/descendant::span[@class='instancename']");

By.XPath("//span[@class='instancename']");

By.XPath("//span[@class='accesshide ']/..");

By.ClassName("instancename");

By.CssSelector("span.instancename");

By.XPath("//span[text()='Link Text']");
```

Comment: I have been trying to get link text from a nested span element so that I can iterate and click through those links. However, using getText() 
returns text from both the span with new lines inserted. I don't seem 
to get it why it prints weird results when the child element is hidden 
through CSS .

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver code:

```
List <WebElement> summaryLinks = 
summary.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.instancename")); 
List <String> links = new ArrayList <String> (); 
for (int i=0; i<summaryLinks.size(); i++){ 
        WebElement element =summaryLinks.get(i); 
         if (element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled()){ 
         String str  = element.getText(); 
         links.add(str);}} 
System.out.println(links);
```

results in the following Output:

```
[Announcements 
Forum, Student Lounge 
Forum, Welcome 
Page, Instructor Bio 
URL, Course Schedule 
Page]
```

Now, when I return `links.size()` it returns the correct number of 
elements (i.e. includes only parent span).

I'm not sure whether this is just a print return issue. I tried 
`trim()`, `toString()` before adding the return of `getText()` into links 
but its results are the same.

Comment: Found index of new line using "\n" and returned substring excluding that and it worked fine